# App installed in Teams native is not showing up in iOS Devices

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-teams-js

[Decisions App](https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-gb/product/office/WA104381880?exp=ubp8&tab=Overview) installed in Teams native is not showing up in iOS Devices.
Tons of our users are not able to see nor access it anymore on their iOS phones. And it's been a blocker for iOS users.

This happening with multiple of our customers. Somehow they are not seeing the pinned app from Desktop Teams in Mobile Teams, and not able to find it from the list when trying to install it on Teams Mobile (from the tray)
We tried Reinstalling/ Resetting the Teams App but it didn't help.The issue still exits.

What might be the reason for that?

iOS Version: iOS 16.3 and above.

Teams version: Latest

[microsoft-teams](/questions/tagged/microsoft-teams)

Tried uninstalling and Reinstalling the Teams App yet the [Decisions App](https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-gb/product/office/WA104381880?exp=ubp8&tab=Overview) didn't appear. Tried searching the App in Teams App store but couldn't find it

[microsoft-teams](/questions/tagged/microsoft-teams)

Comment: We checked in iOS 16.3 and we are able to see the decisions app from more option in Teams mobile app. We are checking with engineering team. We will get back to you.

Comment: @Meghana-MSFT Thank you. The issue still exits in the lates update of Teams App.

Comment: We are not able to repro this issue, so could you please share the below details so that it would be helpful to debug.
1. Teams app version details.
2. Could you please confirm if you are checking this in R4(public) ring
3. Can you retry installing the decision app on the desktop/web, in mobile we don't have search and install of apps yet.

Comment: @Meghana-MSFT We are the on latest Teams version 5.3.0.
And we have tried the above given steps. Yet, the issue still exists.

Comment: Thanks, I will share these details with team.

Comment: We are not able to reproduce this issue locally. Could you please share the below details, this will help engineering team in getting towards the solution easier.  1. Would it be possible to get the test accounts from the tenant for validating it. 2. Video recording of the issue with steps, is there any specific step that is followed when installing the decision app, either from app store or from admin pining by tenants.

Comment: Could you please share the above details?

Comment: Here's the link to the video. 

https://app.jiminny.com/export/kZ6iXhDTkWhW0fqDTzOH6RHYOF9vSaYuo2IqYhN4UZAfYFdNOw2OHQ

There is no specific steps in installing the DecisionsApp within Teams.
When the user Install the Teams App from AppStore and logins. The Decisions app is installed by default in Teams. If not the user can search in Teams App store within Teams iOS App and install it. 
Currently the user is not able to find the App from Teams App store in iOS neither gets installed Automatically.

Comment: The user is able to find other DecisionsApp such as Decisions Bot and other Development app(Master, Development, etc. As shown in the video) by Decisions and not the Actual Production App(Decisions)
In the video we have shown two users one which who can not find Decisison App within Teams and the other one has it. 

Unfortunately we can not provide a Test Tenant account as the issue is on a user basis and not tenant basis and happens only in iOS. 

version:
Teams:  5.3.0
iOS: 16.3.1

Comment: Apologies for the delay, we are not able to reproduce the issue locally. We have raised a bug for the same. We will keep you posted on the updates. Thanks!

Comment: Could you please confirm if you are still facing this issue? Engineering team tried to investigate this issue, but there were also unable to repro the issue.